# Parsing a time span string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing, sql-server-2005

I am reading in from a datasource that is giving me time in a varchar in the format `d:h:m:s:f`, The day portion is always 0, the column represents a time of day. I would like to add this column to a datetime I already have.

```
Entry_Date          Entry_Time
3/3/2009 12:00:00   0:16:17:6:0
8/24/2011 12:00:00  0:8:39:18:0
9/4/2010 12:00:00   0:12:33:18:0
```

If I was using C# I would just do `TimeSpan.ParseExact` but I do not know how to handle this in a purely sql fashion.

I would cast to `time` but I am using Sql Server 2005 and that does not have the `time` type.

How would I add the time to the neighboring datetime?

Comment: You want to merge `Entry_Date` with `Entry_Time` as one `DateTime`?

Comment: @Magnus Yes, that is what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
select Entry_Date + cast(Entry_Time as datetime) combinedCol
from YourTable
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85c3c/1

Enjoy!

---

**Original Asker's note:**

SQL can not handle the fractional seconds however they can be trimed off so the query would be

```
select Entry_Date + cast(left(Entry_Time, len(Entry_Time) - 2) as datetime) combinedCol
from YourTable
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. it can not parse the string "Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string."

Comment: The problem is, you did d:h:m:s, I have d:h:m:s:f, but the fraction seconds is always zero so I could do a `cast(left(Entry_Time, len(Entry_Time) - 2) as datetime)`